# How to increase the quotas on the Google speech API

Tags: google-speech-api

I use Google's speech API but, I have only 50 request per days, I want to know if it's possible to increase this quotas?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently also developing an application that uses the Google Speech API and to my knowledge and my research, Google will probably never give you the option to increase its quota. The Speech API is ment for development with chromium web and is experimental with other applications. Also, **from what I read**, if you do development for chromium web then you wont have the wall of only 50 quota a day. But again I haven't verified this so maybe do some digging into that?

So if this is a limit you cannot take then be creative with your coding or go get another Speech API. For example, I am developing a verbal flash card application for my language class and so since I know I wont have totally "random" accesses to the API (meaning I reuse the resources that Google sends me), I save the audio files to storage for later retrieval if I call upon it again. I built my own *client-server* application as a result to handle all of this.

Keep doing research on the subject (possibly find another API to use that doesn't restrict you), but in all honestly, find a creative approach to using that 50 quota most efficiently. You'd be surprised on what you can think of!